# Login Form Redirection

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

I'm using a theme and the login form on a site at the moment, and when I log in correctly it redirects the user to the appropriate URL.

Unfortunately if i make a mistake in the username/password or if all fields username/password are blank then it forwards you to `wp-login.php`, which shakes its box at the user. And disrupts consistent brand experience. I want to show all errors on my custom login page, not in default `wp-login.php`

So does anybody know a way to how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these two blocks of code to `functions.php` or make a plugin. Everything should be self explanatory with comments.

You could also use [jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to check username, password via ajax and have these 2 blocks of code for backup if user has disabled JS.

These two blocks of code should cover all possible failed login scenarios:

- both inputs are blank
- one input is blank
- both inputs are incorrect
- one of the inputs is incorrect

---

```
//Login failed - username and password entered but incorrect 
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'damn_login_failed' );

function damn_login_failed( $user ) {

    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    //Make sure we don't already have a failed login attempt to prevent double query string
    if ( ! strstr( $referrer, '?login=failed' ) ) {

        //Redirect to CURRENT page and append a querystring of login failed
        wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
    } 
    else {

        wp_redirect( $referrer );
    }

    exit;
}


//Login failed - no username and password entered
add_action( 'authenticate', 'damn_login_blank' );

function damn_login_blank( $user ) {

    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) ) {

        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    }
    else {

        $referrer = '';
    }

    $error = false;

    //Check your username and password inputs - these might be different if you changed them - 'log' is the name attribute of username and 'pwd' for password, just change to whatever you have
    if( isset( $_POST['log'] ) && $_POST['log'] == '' || isset( $_POST['pwd'] ) && $_POST['pwd'] == '' ) {

        $error = true;
    }

    //Check that we're not on the default login page
    if ( ! empty( $referrer ) && ! strstr( $referrer,'wp-login' ) && ! strstr( $referrer, 'wp-admin' ) && $error ) {

        //Make sure we don't already have a failed login attempt to prevent double query string
        if ( ! strstr( $referrer, '?login=failed' ) ) {

            //Redirect to CURRENT page and append a querystring of login failed
            wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );
        } 
        else {

            wp_redirect( $referrer );
        }

        exit;
    }
}
```